# Param is missing or the value is empty: vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this newbie error when i want to upvote a "hack" :

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing at /hacks/6/upvote
param is missing or the value is empty: vote
```

With Request parameters exemple :

```
{"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"r+fYieTQDsD6fuonr3oe0YEzkzBXH1S8k6bDENS0wCVr3LEpxGA4mps5saM4RQLvBNDVzsm2zXpGm9TKe3ZIYA==", 
 "controller"=>"hacks", "action"=>"upvote", "id"=>"6"}
```

I don't understand why my @vote do not appear in parameters...

**Controller hacks_controller.rb**

```
class HacksController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:upvote]

  def upvote
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)
    @hack = Hack.find(params[:id])
    # raise
    @vote.hack = @hack

    if @vote.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      p 'Problème de @vote.save !'
    end
  end

  private

  def vote_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(:hack_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

**Model Vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hack

  validates :hack, presence: true
end
```

Thanks !

Comment: "why my vote do not appear in parameters" - because you don't send it. Must be a problem with the form, or something like that.

Comment: In fact, there is no form ; it's a direct link on the home page with a `<%= link_to "Upvote", upvote_hack_path(hack), method: :post %>`

Comment: "In fact, there is no form" - Well, there's your problem. You might get it working by doing `upvote_hack_path(hack, vote: { vote_id: 123})` (but I'm not sure).

Comment: Ok, i understand. Thanks @SergioTulentsev.

Answer (score 2):

The Rails strong parameters are meant as mass assignment protection and are not suited to this case.

To create an additional CRUD method properly you can just add the additional route to resources:

```
resources :hacks do
  post :upvote
  delete :downvote
end
```

Note that we are using `POST` not `GET` as this is a non-idempotent operation.

You also don't need to pass any parameters. `:hacks_id` will be present in the path and you should fetch the current user id from the session and not the request parameters.

Passing a user id via the parameters is a really bad practice as its very trivial to spoof by using just the web inspector.

```
class HacksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_hack!, except: [:new, :index, :create]

  # POST /hacks/:hack_id/upvote
  def upvote
    @vote = @hack.votes.new(user: current_user)
    if @vote.save
      redirect_to @hack, success: 'Vote created'
    else
      redirect_to @hack, error: 'Vote could not be created'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /hacks/:hack_id/downvote
  def downvote
    @vote = @hack.votes.where(user: current_user).first!
    @vote.destroy
    redirect_to @vote, success: 'Vote deleted'
  end

  private

  # this will raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if
  # the id or hack_id param is not valid. This triggers a 404 response
  def set_hack!
    if params[:id].present?
      Hack.find(params[:id])
    else
      Hack.find(params[:hack_id])
    end 
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can create the links / buttons like so:

```
<% if current_user && @hack.votes.where(user: current_user) %>
  <%= button_to 'Downvote', hack_downvote_path(@hack), method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'Upvote', hack_upvote_path(@hack), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a max @max for your clean directions, it's very helpful !